# Meteor - Angular 2 Flex Layout Mobile Issue

Tags: angular, meteor

I'm developing with Meteor - Angular2 Using Angular 2's Flex Layout

I want a responsive result when screen size goes to smaller than 520px.

It works well just resize my screen, but using real device or chrome's device toolbar It goes to suck..

Here is my screen shot of result, and codes

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-responsive-layout-direction',
  template: `
        <div class="containerX">
          <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout.sm="column" fxFlex class="coloredContainerX box" >
            <div fxFlex> I'm above on mobile, and to the left on larger devices.   </div>
            <div fxFlex> I'm below on mobile, and to the right on larger devices.  </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  `
})
export class DemoResponsiveLayoutDirection {  }
```

**Result Images**

[Working with Screen Resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSjPC.png)

[Not Working with Mobile mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQCDm.png)

Comment: In your 2nd screenshot ("mobile" mode) your viewport is 510px wide (but displayed at 50% zoom), which is above your media query threshold of 500px according to your question.

Comment: Sorry for my mistype (I've changed 500 to 520px). But, the real problem is that same code don't work in real device or chrome device toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself!!

You should add this meta tag to your main.html (or index.html) for detect mobile device properly (not just screen size)

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Your Site Title</title>
</head>
```